Asymptotic formula for sum of $\frac{1}{n^\lambda}$ over square free $n\leq x$
I'd like to get an asymptotic formula for $\sum_{\substack{n\leq x\\ n\text{ square free}}}\frac{1}{n^l}$ for $l>0$.
We know that $\sum_{\substack{n\leq x\\ n\text{ square free}}}1= cx+O(\sqrt{x})$.
Suppose $l>1$, if I use partial summation for $\sum_{\substack{n\leq x\\ n\text{ square free}}}\frac{1}{n^l}$, then I get the error term is larger than main term (since the main term is $x^{1-l}$ and the error term is $O(1)$). Is there a  way to get an asymptotic formula for $\sum_{\substack{n\leq x\\ n\text{ square free}}}\frac{1}{n^l}$?

What’s $,,, n\ square\ free$ ?.

@FelixMarin It means the summation is over square-free integers $n$. An integer is square-free if its prime factorization has exactly one factor for each prime that appears in it.

Apart from the "square free" condition, you may want to check Generalized harmonic numbers, e.g. here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

Well when x is taken to infinity is equal too $\frac{\zeta (\lambda)}{\zeta (2\lambda)}$ as the square free condition is just the absolute value of the mobius function. Im unsure how to find the exact asmytotics for partial expansions.

If you only care about the main term then a quick calculation using partial summation gives $(c-\frac{l}{l+1})x^{1-l}$ for $l<1$, and for $l>1$ the main term is $\zeta(l)/\zeta(2l)$ as mentioned by @AidanR.S.
